# JHipster RedirectingEurekaHttpClient Request execution error

Tags: java-8, jhipster

I setup a basic JHipster Microservice app with MySQL DB. JHipster show the successfully building project. after i running the project with the **./gradelw** command i got the ERROR 6775 in Eureka server running. 
how i can fix it?

```
ERROR 6775 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution 
error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/}
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.register(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:57)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:850)
at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
```

Comment: See official doc for running the registry: https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#-the-jhipster-registry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error come from EUREKA.
Download the **jhipster-registry** from the : [jhipster-registry github repository](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/releases) move it wherever you want and add the read and write permission to it with this command:

```
chmod 755 jhipster-registry-<version>.jar
```

replace the version with the JAR file version that you download.
run the jar file with this command:

```
java -jar jhipster-registry-<version>.jar --spring.security.user.password=admin --jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.secret=my-secret-key-which-should-be-changed-in-production-and-be-base64-encoded --spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.type=native --spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.search-locations=file:./central-config
```

remember to replace the version with the version that you downloaded.

after running successfully you can run the microservice.

Comment: Why using `sudo`?

Comment: it was my mistake thank you for mention it. i edited that. 
@GaëlMarziou